# Are these iptables rules equivalent?

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables, routing

Can someone tell if these iptables are equivalent?

**Version 1**

```
$IPT -F
$IPT -X

$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.1/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

$IPT -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -i eth1 -s 192.168.0.1/24
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

**Version 2**

```
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

$IPT -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.245.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

What I find confusing is that *Version 1* doesn't have explicit ACCEPT rules and an postrouting accept policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rulesets are equivalent, but:

- The first version accept packets of 192.168.0.1/24 on incoming interface eth1, but there is no final drop for all other packets.
- The initial ruleset at startup is "accept all", so you dont need to set it to this state.

So the first version look like this:

```
    $IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.1/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    $IPT -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -i eth1 -s 192.168.0.1/24
    $IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

and the second one:

```
    $IPT -F
    $IPT -X

    $IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.245.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

The difference are the two ACCEPT rules, which have no effect, because there a no DROP rule for other packets.

It is **not** recommended to filter packets outside of the "filter" tables. So don't drop packets outside "filter" tables.
An Example:

```
    $IPT -t nat -A PRETROUTING -s 192.168.245.0/24 -j DROP
```

A packet traversal picture for iptables/netfilter: http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg

A really wonderfull and complete tutorial about iptables/netfilter is here: http://www.frozentux.net/documents/iptables-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that out. What does it mean to "filter packets outside of the filter tables"? Do you have a Wrong and Right example?

Comment: See my posting for the example